# Rails Send PDF as downloadble file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to send pdf file from rails to browser. it just normal call to the api with .pdf at the end. like

```
/detail/ac67857a-ad71-4a97-9718-c71c47e2e4bc.pdf
```

this is my controller code

```
format.pdf {
        download_result_from_aws = export_pdf_service.get_file_from_aws(upload_result[:key])
        File.open(download_result_from_aws, 'r') do |f|
          send_data f.read.force_encoding('BINARY'), :filename => export_pdf_service.filename, :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => "attachment"
        end
      }
```

but it's not getting downloaded. the respon just like this

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<<
/Title (þÿ)
/Creator (þÿwkhtmltopdf 0.12.4)
/Producer (þÿQt 4.8.7)
/CreationDate (D:20190702155100+07'00')
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Type /ExtGState
/SA true
/SM 0.02
/ca 1.0
/CA 1.0
/AIS false
/SMask /None>>
endobj
4 0 obj
[/Pattern /DeviceRGB]
endobj
7 0 obj
<<
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Width 600
/Height 714
/BitsPerComponent 8
/ColorSpace /DeviceGray
/Length 8 0 R
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
xíwÅÇ7×£7éÒ-tTP¢"ØfAE¨ØP~º
©ôÞ98:å¸^r)óý
```

how to fix that?
thank you kindly

Comment: Are you using an AJAX request or just a simple `<a href='' />` ?

Comment: i am using react. with just simple fetch get request @nikamanish